# Redirect to other page when a user cancels Facebook App 'Allow Access'

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

We want to redirect a user after cancelling allow access. Currently, it loads the user's news feed.  Any ideas how or if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar problem. I wanted to redirect the user to my website, after I receive the temporary access_token from Facebook. Though this would be when it authorizes the app( allows access). However, if he does not grant access, the redirect should be same. Try to do something like this:

```
<a id="link" align="center" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=token&scope=PERMISSION_1,PERMISSION_2&redirect_uri=YOUR_WEBSITE"> TEXT </a>
```